# How many worlds are there during branching in the many worlds interpretation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements, quantum-interpretations

### Background and Question

"Measurements are modelled as interactions between subsystems of the universe and manifest themselves as a branching of the universal state." - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_friend)

What is the cardinality of the set of universes that branch out from a particular universe?

Essentially I am under the impression that while everyone within the many world interpretation of quantum  mechanics agree on branching I feel they are vague on how many worlds exist due to this branching.

Comment: To whomever answered the question and then deleted it: I found the answer interesting and was going to ask since measure theory does make sense in QM if there was any way that could be used to divide the area? (sorry if this is irrelevant but I didnt have too much time to read the answer let alone ponder it's implications)

Comment: To be an "interpretation" the theory must use the same mathematics as the other "interpretations". In the   path integral mathematical formulation of quantum mechanics it is obvious that there are infinite possible paths. Interpreting them as different worlds does not reduce the infinities. imo in any mathematical formulation of many worlds the same will be true. Otherwise it is not an "interpretation" but a new theory replacing quantum mechanics!

Comment: Surely in the case of quantum mechanics where measure theory is well defined .. One can answer this kind of question? Infact I suspect the many worlds would have the same cardinality as the infinite possible paths (?). I feel the essense of what your saying is in many worlds they use branching but have no precise idea of what their talking about?

Comment: Yes, I think they hand wave their "interpretation" but are not in a position mathematically  to support it, imo.

Comment: While I have similar fears I hope to be proven wrong by asking this question.

Comment: look at a polemic https://motls.blogspot.com/2019/09/mwi-in-quanta-magazine.html#more

Comment: Look at our own platform: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/307854/did-lubo%c5%a1-motl-really-disprove-the-many-worlds-interpretation (To be fair a person in the chatroom just posted this before your comment)

Comment: We don’t even know whether the (entire) universe has finite or infinite spatial volume, or what its microscopic dimensionality is, so how could we possibly know the cardinality of the paths in a path integral? What would you *do* with this cardinality if you knew it?

Comment: I'm not sure if the cardinality is even different both cases but one can try to answer separately in both cases (if that helps).

Comment: We also don’t know whether spacetime is granular. It could be that the cardinality is a large *finite* number.

Comment: Also "what its microscopic dimensionality is" I am giving the freedom to do this under the context of QM where measure theory is well defined ...

Comment: "We also don’t know whether spacetime is granular. It could be that the cardinality is a large finite number." see escape route above ^

Comment: QM is done in a particular number of dimensions. And we’re not sure know what that number is.

Comment: It's done in a fock space which atleast not the countable infinitiy ... Personally, the way the comments are going I wouldn't be surprised if in the TOE and many worlds are combined we have a definite answer on the continuum hypothesis

Comment: I don’t know what “escape route” you mean. I’m being warned to avoid an extended discussion, so I’m done. My point of view is that the answer to your question is “A lot”.

Comment: To be fair the impression I get from "many worlders" (atleast the vocal ones) is that many worlds "makes sense" and "complete" ... End of story

Comment: @Stéphane Rollandin the way you've edited my question it sounds that universes are merging together as opposed to my opposite intent ... But then again I might be brain dead by now (been awake all night)

Comment: Feel free to reverse my edit, I just tried to make sense of your sentence. Sorry if it is not the meaning you intended.

Comment: If you notice my history of questions I've spent all night (and reached morning) asking interpretational issues I don't understand ... So I'm under the impression my brain is dead by now ... Can you make it clearer what you meant to say if not what I read from it?

Comment: Your last edit (v3) is fine. It actually means the opposite of what I first understood :)

Comment: If you study logic and measure theory you will realize that MWI is ill-defined and has no value. Even CI (Copenhagen interpreation) is better than MWI, though still wrong. I say more [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1579305).

Answer (score 3):

The many worlds interpretation (MWI) takes quantum mechanics (QM) seriously as a description of how the world works.

A measurement is an interaction that takes information from a system that can be copied into other systems. This copyable information for a particular interaction consists of eigenvalues of some observable:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3245

If information about some observable is copied widely then that prevents interference between versions of the system with different values of that observable. The suppression of interference makes these different versions act like a collection of parallel universes to a good approximation:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033

The set of values of an observable form a discrete and finite set for any finite system. So the number of distinguishable versions of a system is some finite but large number. To calculate the number of universes that could be produced you would do something like the calculations of entropy in "Universal upper bound on the entropy-to-energy ratio for bounded systems":

http://old.phys.huji.ac.il/~bekenste/PRD23-287-1981.pdf

This number isn't particularly interesting or fundamental and it doesn't really matter for making predictions, so there's not much reason to calculate it.

Now, if we look at some particular member of the set of measurable values, it has a real valued number that represents the probability of getting that result. So each branch consists of a set of instances of a system that aren't distinguishable by any measurement. The "number" of instances is either a real number or a continuous infinity depending on how you want to think about it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You seem to be saying the number of the branches depend on experiment outcomes? Also In the case of infinity is it $2^{\aleph_0}$ or greater?

Comment: The number of instances in each branch has the same cardinality as the set of real numbers, which is $2^{\aleph_0}$. The number of branches depends on the details of the interactions of the systems involved, and since those interactions are used in experiments the number of possible experimental outcomes is related to the number of branches.

Comment: Ah ... I was under the impression that it always the same infinity however when there are a finite number of outcomes (say $2$) you have half outcomes A and the other half B.

Comment: No. The probabilities have to add up to 1 but they don't always have to be 0.5 and 0.5.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that and was providing an example when I said "(say $2$)" ... Yes there can be systems where there are $2$ outcomes of say $ .7$ and $.3$

Comment: But yes you are right I wasn't clear enough

Comment: after some thinking let's say I flip a quantum coin with $.5$ and $.5$ probabilities then I need $2$ worlds? Let's say it's a skewed quantum coin with $.7$ and $.3$ then I need $10$ worlds? Let's say it's a weirdly-skewed  quantum coin with probabilities $\frac{1}{3^{1/2}}$ and $1 - \frac{1}{3^{1/2}}$ then how many worlds do I need?

Comment: I suspect this line is problematic due to the above comment: "The set of values of an observable form a discrete and finite set for any finite system. So the number of distinguishable versions of a system is some finite but large number."

Comment: If there are two possible outcomes of a measurement, then there are two worlds after the measurement no matter what the probabilities are. Each world has a real number associated with it that gives the probability. That probability doesn't come from counting worlds, see https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906015