# Universal Path Integral & the Many-worlds interpretation (MWI)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, quantum-interpretations

I was wondering if the universal wave function can be thought of using a path integral approach? And if so, does each path correspond to a "branch" of the [MWI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) of QM? Or have I misunderstood what is meant by a MWI branch?

Comment: If you're asking about the MWI see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/502211/

Comment: I am referring to the MWI of QM. But the question linked by alanf, while appreciated, certainly doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branches in the MWI are coarse-grained emergent things, and their number cannot be precisely quantified (see https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199546961.001.0001/acprof-9780199546961-chapter-4 ). Depending on how finely you coarse-grain worlds and how the measurement is performed, more or less paths in the path integral may contribute significantly to each branch.

If you work only at the level of "individual" paths and define each path as a branch, like some sort of quantum Laplace's demon, then you must be very comfortable with some of your branches interfering with each other indefinitely rather than decohering into approximately separate worlds. By refusing to coarse-grain, you haven't really isolated any branching structure at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Your answer is incisive and appreciated. I suppose I'm not uncomfortable at all with paths (branches for the sake of this question) interfering indefinitely - as it seems to me only those branches which are very similar will contribute much. The dissimilar paths will tend to cancel with eachother. By course graining, I take it you mean considering branches as differing sequences of "measurements", right? Is there any problem in principle with considering us to live on one path, and measurements merely give info on which one? That's my sticking point.

Comment: In other words, is there anything philosphically wrong with considering each course-grained history as simply incomplete information on what our "Laplace demon" knows as our "true" path?

Comment: The "The path integral in quantum-mechanical interpretation" section of this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation article seems to suggest as much. Particularly this reference https://www2.perimeterinstitute.ca/personal/rsorkin/some.papers/63.eprb.pdf

Comment: Again, I want to emphasize how extraordinarily grateful I am for your clarifications on these points! I've been asking everywhere, and it seems there is not a wide-spread understanding of these concepts.

Comment: Hmm. I think there are some problems with *it's just incomplete information on what "Laplace's demon" knows as our "true" path*. Mainly, there is no *true* path. Upon measurement, the state $(|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle)$ $\otimes$ $|\uparrow \downarrow$observer$\rangle$ evolves into $|\uparrow\rangle\otimes|$observer who saw $\uparrow\rangle$ + $|\downarrow\rangle \otimes|$observer who saw $\downarrow\rangle$. Laplace's demon would predict exactly that: one person / world evolving into two. This is true even in the path integral formalism.

Comment: This is all if the demon even cares to talk about coarse-grained things like "people" or "worlds" rather than just the universal wavefunction or individual terms in the path integral. And if not, things like people and worlds do not exist soley on a single term of the path integral (as we can see interference effects in our experiments).

Comment: Ah, I think I see the sticking point. I've read that it's possible to see QM as a mere extension of normal probability to the L2 norm. Unlike a normal random walk, this allows for the random time evolution of one variable to preclude certain evolutions of a second variable (i.e. interference). Suppose we consider interference to be a consequence of this  generalization of probability, rather than an interaction between branches. Couldn't we say that in the limit of a continuously infinite series of random time evolutions (ALL known to our Laplace Demon) our universe consists of a single path?

Comment: Of course, even in regular probability, the measure of a single point is zero. Then would you prefer to say we inhabit the set of paths consistent with all historical observations made so far, but that this set converges to a single path as time approaches infinity? Thanks again for your help. I think these last questions of mine should put my mind at ease.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Although I think you are now talking about an interpretation different enough from the regular MWI to deserve a new name. Especially as the MWI is fully deterministic (apart from our subjective self-locating uncertainty of which branch we are on), but probabilities seem to play a fundamental role in what you are describing.

Comment: I suppose it's a matter of philosophy as to whether or not you consider us to be one of many possible paths, or one of many actual paths, in which case you could still consider the dynamics as deterministic. Isn't my idea just a matter or considering infinitely fine grained universes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the path-integral approach in the many-worlds formulation of QM but no, the paths of the path integral do not correspond to the branches of the many-worlds formulation of QM. Branching is associated with measurements. On the other hand, the path integral makes no reference to entanglement or decoherence -- the two crucial elements of a measurement process. As an extreme example, consider the following: in a world of a single particle with nothing else, there is no branching. However, obviously, you can still use path integral to calculate the time-evolution of the wavefunction of this particle.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm still not satisfied. It seems to me that decoherence is trivially included in a universal path integral approach. All usual quantum mechanics should apply, and quantum uncertainty may be interpreted as self-locating uncertainty among all possible trajectories of the universe. The probabilities for divergent time evolution of previously identical universes is still given by the sum-over-histories approach...

Comment: In particular, were you to include the experimentalist, the measurement apparatus, and the system to be measured in the same (truly monstrous) path integral, you'd find the probability of measuring e.g. spin-up when the particle was actually spin-down as near zero, and vice versa, which of course is another perspective on decoherence.

Comment: This, according to my understanding, is because a whole lot of coincidences would have to happen to many trillions of particles (i.e. those making up the measurement apparatus, the experimenter, & the environment) in order to provide a faulty measurement, and the amplitudes of these coincidences end up cancelling out in the path integral.