# MWI and each path in a Feynman Integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, quantum-interpretations

I have been looking into the [MWI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) of QM, and I wonder if it implies that we should consider each trajectory in a Feynman Path integral as being "equally real", and that we simply inhabit the universe where one such trajectory occurs. This certainly seems to be David Deutsch's interpretation.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/701635/2451

Comment: Duplicate seems to defined by "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." My previous question never got an answer, and I'd like to ask a subtly different question by avoiding the use of "universal wave function". If you're going to close any question, I'd prefer to close the previous one.

Comment: @Qmechanic Would you hazard a brief answer? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Universal Path Integral & the Many-worlds interpretation (MWI)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/701635/)

Comment: Voting to close this one, I have provided a brief answer to your older post. I will try to expand on it a bit more later today.